# Serverless Framework S3 Dev/Pro Env Yaml

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, serverless-framework

In my Serverless Framework .yml file I'm trying to create an S3 bucket for prod and dev. My current serverless.yml looks like this:

```
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  region: us-east-1
  profile: default
  environment:
    BUCKET_NAME: !Ref myappBucket
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "s3:DeleteObject"
            - "s3:GetObject"
            - "s3:PutObject"
          Resource:
            Fn::Join:
              - ""
              - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                - Ref: myappBucket
                - "/*"

resources:
  Resources:
    myappBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: myapp
        PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
          BlockPublicAcls: true
          BlockPublicPolicy: true
          IgnorePublicAcls: true
          RestrictPublicBuckets: true
```

In the [docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#recursively-reference-properties) they show how to setup a prod and dev environment. I created a dev and prod config file:

```
// config.dev.json -- the prod file looks the same but with "prod" instead of "dev"
{
  "BUCKET_NAME": "myappBucket-dev",
  "NAME": "myapp-dev"
}
```

In the serverless.yml I then replaced the `provider` code like so:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  region: us-east-1
  profile: default
  environment:
    BUCKET_NAME: !Ref ${file(./config.${opt:stage, 'dev'}.json):BUCKET_NAME}
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "s3:DeleteObject"
            - "s3:GetObject"
            - "s3:PutObject"
          Resource:
            Fn::Join:
              - ""
              - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                - Ref: ${file(./config.${opt:stage, 'dev'}.json):BUCKET_NAME}
                - "/*"
```

but I am unsure what to do in the `resource` area. How do I replace the key "myappBucket"? I tried a few things but I keep running into this error when I run `sls deploy --stage dev` :

`The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [myapp-dev] in the Resources block of the template`

Looking for the best way to let the .yml file handle S3 when setting the stage flag in the `sls deploy` command.